# How can I Pass a JavaScript ES6 Arrow Function as a Parameter

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm trying to `.sort()` an array of objects, but my javascript knowledge isn't strong enough to rewrite the comparator function to accept an arrow function to find the `key` on the objects rather than use a string.  Any help refactoring this would be appreciated:

My comparison function:

```js
compareValues = (key, order = "ascending") => {
      let result = 0;

      return function(lhs, rhs) {
        if (!(lhs.hasOwnProperty(key) && rhs.hasOwnProperty(key))) {
          return result; // property is missing; comparison is impossible
        }

        const l = lhs[key].toLowerCase() || lhs[key];
        const r = rhs[key].toLowerCase() || rhs[key];

        result = (l > r) ? 1 : (l < r) ? -1 : 0;

        return result * (order === "ascending") ? 1 : -1;
      };
    };
```

which is used in the conventional way:

```js
objects.sort(compareValues("name")); // or
objects.sort(compareValues("name", descending));
```

The goal is to be able to use it thusly:

```js
objects.sort(compareValues(o => o.name));
```

... but frankly I haven't used JS much until lately, so I suck at it.

Comment: javascript doesnt have c# with lambda expression trees.

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to pass a `comparator` function into `compareValues`? Based on your function's signature, it expects a `key`, which looks like it's a `string`, but you're trying to pass a `function` instead.

Comment: Check `key` in `compareValues`. If it's a function, run it, and use that as the key to look up. If it isn't a function use it as the key.

Comment: @DanielA.White But it's not necessary. That's the power of first-class functions: they are first-class and don't need to be handled in an OO manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to perform checks on objects to see if they have specific properties because you would know for sure. So this is how I see it.

---

```js
const comparer= (select, descend = false) => (a, b) => {
    let lhs = select(a); let rhs = select(b);
    if (lhs < rhs) return descend ? 1 : -1;
    if (lhs > rhs) return descend ? -1 : 1;
    return 0;
}

let arr = [{ id: 1, name: "Clara" }, { id: 2, name: "Abraham" }, { id: 3, name: "Brian" }]

arr.sort(comparer(o => o.name))
console.log(arr);

arr.sort(comparer(o => o.name, true))
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
const compareValues = (pickProp, order = 'ascending') => {
    let result = 0

    return (lhs, rhs) => {
        const l = pickProp(lhs) // pickProp is passed #first-class
        const r = pickProp(rhs)
        if (!l && !r) {
            return 0 // Quick callout here, comparators only ever return -1, 0, or 1.
        }

        result = l > r ? 1 : l < r ? -1 : 0

        // Leveraging your default values here for cleaner signature
        return result * (order === 'ascending') ? 1 : -1
    }
}

list.sort(compareValues(o => o.name))
// or even 
list.sort(compareValues(o => o.name), 'descending')
```

I believe thats in-line with your question.

Comment: A little comment explaining how it works would be great. I don't mean comment every line, just bring attention to the core idea of a picker function

Comment: Yea sure. One sec.

Comment: Updated, let me know if you want something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closer you can get with what you want is this:

```js
let compareValues = (key, order = "ascending") => {
  let result = 0;

  return function(lhs, rhs) {
    if (!(key(lhs) && key(rhs))) {
      return result; // property is invalid; comparison is impossible
    }

    const l = key(lhs).toLowerCase() || key(lhs);
    const r = key(rhs).toLowerCase() || key(rhs);

    result = (l > r) ? 1 : (l < r) ? -1 : 0;

    return result * (order === "ascending") ? 1 : -1;
  };
};

let objects = [{
  "name": "Mary"
}, {
  "name": "John"
}];

objects.sort(compareValues(o => o.name));

console.log(objects);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work.  The `objects` are in the same order they went in.

Comment: @ScottBaker to me the snippet's console shows: John, Mary.

Comment: I see Mary, John

Comment: @ScottBaker tested in Chrome and indeed, it displays Mary, John. In FF it doesn't.